# Plotly hover events in a IPython Notebook

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm trying to display a small picture when hovering over a specific bar of a bar-chart. This using plotly inside a IPython notebook.
Plot.ly have a nice example of this using javascript [here](https://plot.ly/python/hover-events/). 
I can easily embed this example inside the notebook using the approach shown [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/01/ipython-notebook-javascript-python-communication/), but I really would like to use the plot from the notebook. 
I think I am almost there:

```
      iplot({'data':data, 'layout':layout})
```

is the python code to generate the plot; it embeds directly a svg in the cell.

In the javascript example, an iframe is generated:

```
      <iframe id="plot" src="..." seamless></iframe>`
```

The javascript can then get the iframe by id:

```
      Plot.iframe = document.getElementById("plot");
```

I've tried a few things without success; the iplot doesn't create any iframe. How can I link the javascript to the python code? 
i.e. what 'id' can I use?

Thanks,
N

Comment: I guess is far too long to ask if you found a solution.